# left join returns NULL despite that there are matches in all tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables that not related by foreign key. TABLE_A CODE column type is nvarchar(10), TABLE_B CODE column type is nvarchar(2), CodeID column type is bigint. Table_B contains more than 3 millions of rows, I will just provide some short sample:

```
    TABLE_A
    CodeId   | CODE    
    11       | DS      
    12       | TR     
    13       | MP     
    14       | KD 
    15       | 2A
    16       | AC    
    ...

    TABLE_B
    ID      | CODE  
    1       | DS     
    2       | DS      
    3       | DS      
    4       | TR    
    5       | TR    
    6       | MP    
    7       | KD      
    8       | KD   
    9       | 2A
    10      | AC
    11      | AC 
    ...
```

I want to get in result set for each CODE from TABLE_B associated CodeId from TABLE_A, desired output:

```
     RESULT SET
        ID      | CODE  | CODEID
        1       | DS    | 11
        2       | DS    | 11
        3       | DS    | 11
        4       | TR    | 12
        5       | TR    | 12
         ...
```

I tried left join tables

```
 Select * FROM  TABLE_B AS B 
left JOIN TABLE A AS A on A.CODE=B.CODE
```

but for some Code values like 2A, AC it returns Null in CodeId column of result set despite that there are matches in both tables.

**UPDATE**
I just executed query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A where CODE in ('2A', 'AC')
```

and I haven't got any results in output.
But after executing

```
SELECT CODE FROM TABLE_A
```

I have got rows with 2A and AC values in it in CODE column.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Two tables without relations? I daresay they are related by using the same set of codes. It even looks like table_a is the code table and table_b uses its codes.

Comment: Can TABLE_B.CODE be null? Then of course you see nulls in your results. Else: Is there any record in TABLE_B with a code also present in TABLE_A and with an associated CODEID in that TABLE_A record, and you get that record with CODEID null, though? That should not be possible.

Comment: Those tables have a relation  A.code=B.Code. You need to look closer as what you think is a match is not truly a match.  Provide data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What is the type for the CODE fields in each table. Have you checked for trailing spaces in some but not all of the code values?

Comment: Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) There is no point in we trying to guess what you want. For example why you include date field when is always same value? or why you include `other columns`? Those don't add info for the question. Just keep things simple and show us all the cases in your sample.

Comment: Again please read the link, we dont need your private info. Just keep things simple as you can. You will get answer faster if we understand the problem quickly

Comment: May be you should chech collations of those columns...

Comment: `SELECT '#' + CODE + '#' FROM TABLE_A` to see the trailing spaces. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A where ltrim(rtrim(CODE)) in ('2A', 'AC')` will probably return rows.

Answer (score 0):

A normal join query would do, what you need. Try this:

```
select t2.id, t2.code, t2.date, t1.codeID 
   from table_B t2 join table_A t1 on (t2.code = t1.code)
```

You can see the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e43be/3) here.

Comment: What do you want if the CODEID is null? Can you please update your question with the required results set in case of nulls?

Comment: There is no `codeID` column in Table_2 as per what you have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Than are there nulls in the `code` column in table_B?

Comment: Than which nulls you want? Please clarify your question. It's unclear now to me.

Comment: If there are no nulls, then your statement `it will not include all the rows that returns null in CODEID column` is irrelevant.

Comment: @AndreiKarcheuski If this doesn't solve your question. You need to rewrite your question with all the cases in the sample data and the desire output.

Comment: My sentence  `it will not include all the rows that returns null in CODEID column  was relevant` - there was no nulls in a table, but 
were nulls in result set of left join query. All samples were provided as well as desired output before this answer.